# How to remove space from phone number (SQL)

Tags: sql, string, select, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have phone numbers in the following format:
03 12345678 and 0412 3456789

I need to remove the space from the numbers so that I can join to another table where number format is 0312345679 and 04123456789. I do not want to update the table.

I have tried to run the following query for the home number format, but keep getting an error:

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(p.Home_Phone_Num, ' ', '') AS Home_Num
FROM table
```

The error:

> Syntax error: expected something between the 'SELECT' keyword and the 'REPLACE' keyword.

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Try putting the `SELECT `nad `REPLACE()` on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a Teradata error message. This database does not have a `replace()` function - instead, you need [`oreplace()`](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/4EDh6YkzUpaKM7mjAXO1PA):

```
select oreplace(p.Home_Phone_Num, ' ', '') as Home_Num from mytable
```

Comment: Yes, I am using Teradata SQL assistant. thank you this has solved it!

Answer (score 0):

To remove single characters there's no need for oReplace, use oTranslate instead:

```
oTranslate (p.Home_Phone_Num, ' ', '') AS Home_Num
```

This might also replace additional characters

```
oTranslate (p.Home_Phone_Num, ' -/()', '') AS Home_Num
```

Comment: I rarely use either of these. Why is oTranslate better here?

Comment: @Andrew: Because it's exactly made for replacing characters with another or removing them. A lot of people only know REPLACE and then start using nested REPLACE :-)